# How can I efficiently sort an array of objects in Javascript in different ways?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, optimization

I have this array of objects:

```
[{a:5,b:2},{a:10,b:20},{a:1,b:3},{a:8,b:12}]
```

And I must sort it in different ways. For example for `order = 1` the order must be like this:

```
1.- {a:8,b:12} 2.- {a:10,b:20} 3.- {a:1,b:3} 4.- {a:5,b:2}
```

If `order = 2`

```
1.- {a:10,b:20} 2.- {a:1,b:3} 3.- {a:8,b:12} 4.- {a:5,b:2}
```

If `order = 3`

```
1.- {a:5,b:2} 2.- {a:1,b:3} 3.- {a:8,b:12} 4.- {a:10,b:20}
```

I know I can create a new array and pushing the elements according the different orders like this

```
if(order === 1) {
  oldArray.reduce((a, obj) => {
    if (obj.a === 8) {
      newArray.push(obj);
    }
    return a;
  }, []);
  oldArray.reduce((a, obj) => {
     if (obj.a === 10) {
       newArray.push(obj);
     }
        return a;
      }, []);
  }
```

And so on, is there a way to fix it with fewer lines of code?

Comment: Is there any rule between `order` number and the actual order? Or is it like completely custom/random?

Comment: Specify ordering rules and use `array.sort` method.

Comment: @technophyle It is like custom order. There's no relation between `order` and the elements.

Comment: @JanPfeifer I've found examples sorting in ascending or descending order, but not examples with custom sorting like this. Do you know any example? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to "sort" an `oldArray`? Does the input ever change? And if yes, in what ways? It sounds like you could simply hardcode a few constants and return the one for respective `order`.

Comment: If it's completely random, you can just return the full array inside a `switch-case` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to sort anything, you just have different hardcoded orders. Use

```
function getArray(order) {
  if (order == 1) {
    return [{a:8,b:12}, {a:10,b:20}, {a:1,b:3}, {a:5,b:2}];
  }
  if (order == 2) {
    return [{a:10,b:20}, {a:1,b:3}, {a:8,b:12}, {a:5,b:2}];
  }
  if (order == 3) {
    return [{a:5,b:2}, {a:1,b:3}, {a:8,b:12}, {a:10,b:20}];
  }
  throw new Error(`unknown order '${order}'`);
}
```

or if you need to return the same objects every time

```
const a8b12  = {a:8, b:12};
const a10b20 = {a:10,b:20};
const a1b3   = {a:1, b:3 };
const a5b2   = {a:5, b:2 };
function getArray(order) {
  if (order == 1) {
    return [a8b12, a10b20, a1b3, a5b2];
  }
  if (order == 2) {
    return [a10b20, a1b3, a8b12, a5b2];
  }
  if (order == 3) {
    return [a5b2, a1b3, a8b12, a10b20];
  }
  throw new Error(`unknown order '${order}'`);
}
```

Comment: It was like a simple solution, but I was complicating my life. Thanks!